# Possible mistake in a given question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am looking at the following question:

[image]

**I do not wish for someone to give me the answer to it.**

I want to know why does the given solution not obey the boundary conditions. Specifically, when $\theta = 0$ and $r=1$, we have $\phi (r=1,\theta)=0$ and not $\phi (r=1,\theta)=\pi/2$ as per the boundary condition. Why is this OK?

Comment: The Fourier series will give the average value at the discontinuity in $\phi$, which is 0

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!